# SharePoint API $expand past a depth of 2

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to expand a SharePoint API request to go beyond a depth of 2.

I currently have 3 lists a,b and c

A references b which in turn references c. At present I'm having to make multiple requests to fetch the data from a SharePoint list, ideally I would want to do this in a single request.